# Unable to start Camel 1.5.0

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, jms, apache-camel

I'm trying to run the Camel Example "camel-example-spring-jms" (also at http://activemq.apache.org/camel/tutorial-jmsremoting.html).
However, when I try to start Camel using "org.apache.camel.spring.Main" class, I get the error saying

**"Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core]"**

[Note: I'm able to run the example just fine when I use Maven command "mvn exec:java -PCamelServer" ]

Can someone please help me understand what might be causing this. A potential resolution hint will not hurt either :)

++++++ Error Stack +++++

```
Dec 4, 2008 12:45:01 PM org.apache.camel.util.MainSupport doStart
INFO: Apache Camel 1.5.0 starting
Dec 4, 2008 12:45:01 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@1ac3c08: display name [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@1ac3c08]; startup date [Thu Dec 04 12:45:01 EST 2008]; root of context hierarchy
Dec 4, 2008 12:45:01 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from file [C:\dev\camel-example-spring-jms\bin\META-INF\spring\camel-server-aop.xml]
Dec 4, 2008 12:45:02 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from file [C:\dev\camel-example-spring-jms\bin\META-INF\spring\camel-server.xml]
Dec 4, 2008 12:45:03 PM org.apache.camel.util.MainSupport run
SEVERE: Failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative location [camel-server.xml]
Offending resource: file [C:\dev\camel-example-spring-jms\bin\META-INF\spring\camel-server-aop.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core]
Offending resource: file [C:\dev\camel-example-spring-jms\bin\META-INF\spring\camel-server.xml]

org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative location [camel-server.xml]
Offending resource: file [C:\dev\camel-example-spring-jms\bin\META-INF\spring\camel-server-aop.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core]
Offending resource: file [C:\dev\camel-example-spring-jms\bin\META-INF\spring\camel-server.xml]

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:201)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:147)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:132)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:92)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:507)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:398)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:342)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:212)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:113)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:80)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:123)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:353)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
        at org.apache.camel.spring.Main.createDefaultApplicationContext(Main.java:189)
        at org.apache.camel.spring.Main.doStart(Main.java:152)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:47)
        at org.apache.camel.util.MainSupport.run(MainSupport.java:121)
        at org.apache.camel.util.MainSupport.run(MainSupport.java:310)
        at org.apache.camel.spring.Main.main(Main.java:72)
```

++++++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it works fine under maven - but not if you run it how? In your IDE or something?

If you are using eclipse / intellij you can create an IDE project for the maven project using maven.

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

or

```
mvn idea:idea
```

If you are writing some shell script or running it from the command line then its likely you are missing some jars; you'll need spring + jaxb + commons-logging + camel-core, camel-spring and camel-jms.

To get an accurate list of the dependencies in maven type

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

Answer (score 0):

This particular exception is caused when the camel-jms library .jar is not on your classpath.  As mentioned by James, ensure this library is correctly in your classpath when running.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when using camel (although it was camel 1.3). In my case the error was:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate NamespaceHandler for namespace [http://activemq.apache.org/camel/schema/spring]
```

I was able to fix it by changing my jdk version.  I was using jdk 1.5, I upgraded to 1.6 and that solved my problem.  Hope this helps.

Monica

Answer (score 0):

Which version of JDK1.5 are you using? Are you using a different JDK in Eclipse vs. Command line?

Could be an issue with JAXB not having the correct version. Must be JAXB 2.1 or newer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, both inside Eclipse and with external tools (Maven). As James and Pete pointed out, adding camel-jms.jar inside the classpath, solved my problem. It looks like camel-core and camel-jms are the basic mandatory dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.0</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-jms</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.0</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```